# how does the callback in fs.readfile get called when using fs.readfile.bind(context,pathArgument)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, functional-programming

How does the callback in fs.readfile get called when using fs.readfile.bind(context,pathArgument) like so. //understandable because my task function knows the name of the callback parameter

```
async.series([function(callback){
//operation done callback()},...],finalCallback(err,result));
```

BUT 
//not understandable

```
async.series([fs.someOperation.bind(null,firstArgument),...],finalCallback(err,esult))
```

I believe I understand partial application;however, it would look something like this. `function(callback){ fs.someOperation(firstArgument, ????)}(asyncCallbackFunc)` and then I have no idea how the second argument is called... 
Thx, in advance for helping me clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

All `bind` does is set the context of the callback. It is still a regular callback like any other. Except, it is explicitly told what `this` will be. Looks like in your case, it is set to `null`.

Comment: That'ts not how bind is being used here that's why it is null. Have you worked with the async library before or used partial application ?

Answer (score 0):

The `bind` function on function object allows you to set the context i.e the value of `this` inside the function body as well as allow you to create a partial function in case you pass some arguments while calling `bind`.

For example:

```
function add(a,b) { 
  console.log(this);  
  return a+b; 
}

var newAdd = add.bind("hello world", 10);
```

The `newAdd` will be one argument function which gets added to 10 and the result is returned. Also when newAdd is called the "hello world" will be logged in console.

Now when your code says `fs.readFile.bind(null, path)` it means that the return function will be of one argument which is the callback for readfile i.e the return function will be of form `function(callback) { ... }` which is exactly what is required to be passed to `async.series`

The main idea in the code you posted is to create a partial function that accepts only callback so that it can be passed to `async.series` the null argument doesn't play any role but you need to pass a context argument to call bind function, hence a `null` is passed as context arg.

Comment: Now if you continue you will see my point. callback parameter is sent in.... how does the fs.readfile() call the callback like so fs.readfile(path,sentInCallback) --> when finished sentInCallback() but my question is how is it called if you never actually specify the second argument. Yes, 'callback' is the first argument of the newly created function but how does fs.readfile know to take the first argument and use it as a callback? That is my question.